# Adding the timestamp to Acumatica's Inventory Lot/Serial History Page

Tags: acumatica

Currently, the transaction date on the Lot/Serial History page is purely a date, rather than a datetime.

It would be extremely useful in sorting the order of transactions and debugging production issues if there were a time component for the transactions.  It appears the database stores the trandate with 00:00:00 timestamp, so the data is not even available without somehow using the created or modified dates, which are also not readily available.

I'm looking for a suggestion on how to get a timestamp visible in this window. Is there a best practice for getting access to the Created Date Time? Or do I need to create a new field and store the time myself?  Other brilliant suggestions welcome; I also created this as an idea for Acuamtica.  https://feedback.acumatica.com/ideas/ACU-I-1322

Answer (score 1):

You can make a custom unbound field in the INTranSplit DAC that references 'CreatedDateTime' and sets a specific display format in the mask.

The catch is that there's many INTranSplit DAC and the one you're using doesn't declare CreatedDateTime. What you can do is use another INTranSplit DAC or INTran DAC that contains CreatedDateTime with PXDBScalar.

1. Lot/Serial history uses:

   - PX.Objects.**IN.InventoryLotSerInq.INTranSplit**
2. CreatedDateTime is in another DAC with the same name but in a different namespace:

   - PX.Objects.**IN.INTranSplit**
3. CreatedDateTime is also in INTran DAC:

   - PX.Objects.**IN.INTran**

Here's how you can extend InventoryLotSerInq.INTranSplit DAC to add a field that access IN.INTran.CreatedDateTime. Notice 'g' is the date time format that will display date and time, you can use another .Net format if desired:

```
namespace PX.Objects.IN
{
  public class INTranSplitExt : PXCacheExtension<PX.Objects.IN.InventoryLotSerInq.INTranSplit>
  {
      public abstract class usrTranTimestamp : PX.Data.IBqlField { }

      // You can also substitute 'IN.INTranSplit.' by 'IN.INTran.'
      [PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<IN.INTranSplit.createdDateTime, 
                         Where<IN.INTranSplit.docType, Equal<InventoryLotSerInq.INTranSplit.docType>, 
                         And<IN.INTranSplit.refNbr, Equal<InventoryLotSerInq.INTranSplit.refNbr>,
                         And<IN.INTranSplit.lineNbr, Equal<InventoryLotSerInq.INTranSplit.lineNbr>>>>>))]
      [PXDate(DisplayMask = "g", InputMask = "g")]
      [PXUIField(DisplayName="Tran. Timestamp")]
      public virtual DateTime? UsrTranTimestamp { get; set; }
  }
}
```

The new custom unbound field will show created date time but it's not the same as using TranDate because these CreatedDateTime fields are not set at the same time TranDate is set:
[image]

Comment: Note that CreatedDateTime is different than Transaction Date, it refers to the moment the INTranSplit record was created in the database not the  Transaction which explains the discrepancies. To get the exact Transaction Date you will need to create and store it in a new DateTime field when TranDate is set because TranDate doesn't save time.